# Mass changing columns of a data set to numeric

Tags: r, excel

I've imported an excel data set and want to set nearly all columns (greater than 90) to numeric when they are initially characters. What is the best way to achieve this because importing and changing each to numeric one by one isn't the most efficient approach?

Comment: Do you want to do it in excel or you imported the file by code and you want to make the change in your code?

Comment: My mistake, I should've specified this was for R. I'm trying to import an excel dataset but it won't come in as numeric and the stringsAsFactor = FALSE doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You may use `sapply(foo.df, "as.numeric")` to convert variables into numeric form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do as you wish:

```
# Random data frame for illustration (100 columns wide)
df <- data.frame(replicate(100,sample(0:1,1000,rep=TRUE)))

# Check column names / return column number (just encase you wanted to check)
colnames(df)

# Specify columns
cols <- c(1:length(df))   # length(df) is useful as if you ever add more columns at later date

# Or if only want to specify specific column numbers: 
# cols <- c(1:100) 

#With help of magrittr pipe function change all to numeric
library(magrittr)
df[,cols] %<>% lapply(function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))

# Check our columns are numeric
str(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is already imported with all character columns, you can convert the relevant columns to numeric using `mutate_at` by position or name:

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse))  

# Assume the imported excel file has 5 columns a to e
df <- tibble(a = as.character(1:3),
             b = as.character(5:7),
             c = as.character(8:10),
             d = as.character(2:4),
             e = as.character(2:4))

# select the columns by position (convert all except 'b')
df %>% mutate_at(c(1, 3:5), as.numeric)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>       a     b     c     d     e
#>   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     5     8     2     2
#> 2     2     6     9     3     3
#> 3     3     7    10     4     4

# or drop the columns that shouldn't be used ('b' and 'd' should stay as chr)
df %>% mutate_at(-c(2, 4), as.numeric)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>       a     b     c     d     e
#>   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1     1     5     8     2     2
#> 2     2     6     9     3     3
#> 3     3     7    10     4     4

# select the columns by name
df %>% mutate_at(c("a", "c", "d", "e"), as.numeric)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>       a     b     c     d     e
#>   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     5     8     2     2
#> 2     2     6     9     3     3
#> 3     3     7    10     4     4
```